# Kendo UI Treeview not expanding nodes

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a Kendo UI treeview bound to remote data; however, while top level items are showing, and the arrow indicates there are children items, clicking the arrow does nothing but spin--no expansion to show child nodes. Any help would be appreciated.

My code looks like this:

```
var industryTree = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
     transport: {
         read: {
             url: 'http://'+document.domain+'/services/TreeIndustries.php',
             dataType: "json"
         },
         schema: {
             model: {
                id:"id"
             }  
         }
     }
});
```

My tree init:

```
 var industryTreeView=$("#industry-tree").kendoTreeView({
     dataSource: industryTree,
     dataTextField: ["text","text"]

 });
```

The JSON returned validates correctly; anyone wanting a look can check it out here:

```
http://173.45.233.104/services/TreeIndustries.php
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the loadOnDemand property to false as per:  http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#configuration-loadOnDemand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very sorry but seems that there is a limitation on the valid names for "children" and `children` is not a valid name.

There is also the question that you have defined `schema` inside `transport` when they should be at the same level:

```
var industryTree = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: 'http://'+document.domain+'/services/TreeIndustries.php',
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id:"id"
        }
    }
});
```

If you change your JSON and replace `children` by `items`, `kids` or even `_children` it should work.

In addition, remember to set `loadOnDemand` as `false` to have the full tree loaded.

With these, your DataSource should look like:

```
var industryTree = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url     : 'http://' + document.domain + '/services/TreeIndustries.php',
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    schema   : {
        model: {
            id      : "id",
            children: "_children"
        }
    }
});
```

And the tree initialization:

```
var industryTreeView = $("#industry-tree").kendoTreeView({
    loadOnDemand : false,
    dataSource   : industryTree,
    dataTextField: "label"

});
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work either--though I must thank you for noting that I was defining my schema within transport (I hadn't caught that). In the end, I ditched using Kendo's treeview and went with jqtree instead. The treeview component is the only part of Kendo UI I actually had trouble with.

Comment: With the modifications that I propose actually works. Check it in [www.onabai.es/so/index.html](http://www.onabai.es/so/index.html) you can inspect the source and see the modified data in [www.onabai.es/so/data.json](http://www.onabai.es/so/data.json)